# JQuery on Change Event Download File

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, onchange

HTML Code:

```
<span>Download Report as</span>
    <select id="comboFile">
        <option value="none">Select</option>
        <option value="http://somewhere/123.pdf">PDF</option>
        <option value="http://somewhere/123.csv">CSV</option>
    </select>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
       $("#comboFile").change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() != "none") GetFile($(this).val());
        $(this).val("none");
    });
});

function GetFile(fileURL){
///Code to be filled
//window.location.href = fileURL;///Does not seem to work for new window
}
```

I am pretty much stuck.. How do I initiate file download.. I need to fill in the code for Get File function...

Comment: Your code works as given. Setting `window.location` should work: http://jsfiddle.net/XeAzy/. Note that the JavaScript written after setting `window.location` will not be run.

Comment: Define "does not seem to work".

Comment: Sorry my bad I was supposed to say in a hew window. it was supposed to be `window.location.href = fileURL`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
       $("#comboFile").change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() != "none") GetFile($(this).val());
        $(this).val("none");
    });
});

function GetFile(fileURL){
///Code to be filled
//window.open(fileURL);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this opens the file in new window. I want to download it.

Comment: Ahh, okay. In that case, you'll need to write some PHP. Essentially, you'd set the location of that window to something like http://myserver.com/download.php?file=myfile.pdf

Then you need to set your headers and use PHP's readfile() function.

There should be plenty of posts with more details.